# Get the data 'less common as possible' from a collection

Tags: vb.net, linq, group-by

Starting from a table like this:

```
| Code | Year |
---------------
| A01  | 2001 |
| A01  | 2002 |
| B01  | 2002 |
| C01  | 2003 |
```

I have to arrive to this:

```
| Code | Year |
---------------
| A01  | 2001 |
| B01  | 2002 |
| C01  | 2003 |
```

I have to group the first column (Code) and from the second (Year) I have to get the data 'less common as possible' compared to all the other records. I try to explain this with the example: for the code 'A01' I have 2 years: '2001' and '2002'. I have to take '2001' because it's the one that not recurs in the other records. In the case that there aren't available values 'Year' that not recurs in the other records, it's good to take whatever value.

The data are in the form of array in memory and to interact with them I'm useng some LINQ queries.

Thank you in advance!
Pileggi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the right answer (to be compared with Alex Aza's one : filteredItemsAlexAza and filteredItemsSsithra give different results since the less common data is not also the minimum one anymore - here 2005 instead of 2001 for A01)

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var items = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item { Code = "A01", Year = "2005" },
            new Item { Code = "A01", Year = "2002" },
            new Item { Code = "B01", Year = "2002" },
            new Item { Code = "C01", Year = "2003" },
        };

        var filteredItemsAlexAza = items.Select(cod => cod.Code).Distinct().Select(cod => items.OrderBy(itm => itm.Year).First(itm => itm.Code == cod)).ToList();
        var filteredItemsSsithra = items
            .Select(item => new { Item = item, NbItemsWithSameYear = items.Where(i => i.Year == item.Year).Count() })
            .GroupBy(ano => ano.Item.Code)
            .Select(group => group.OrderBy(ano => ano.NbItemsWithSameYear).First().Item)
            .ToList();
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry for making it in C#. Hope you will not have problems to convert it to VB.NET.

```
var filteredItems = items
    .Select(cod => cod.Code).Distinct()
    .Select(cod => items.OrderBy(itm => itm.Year).First(itm => itm.Code == cod))
    .ToList();
```

Test code:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string Year { get; set; }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var items =
        new List<Item>
        {
            new Item{ Code = "A01", Year = "2001" },
            new Item{ Code = "A01", Year = "2002" },
            new Item{ Code = "B01", Year = "2002" },
            new Item{ Code = "C01", Year = "2003" },
        };

    var filteredItems = items
        .Select(cod => cod.Code).Distinct()
        .Select(cod => items.OrderBy(itm => itm.Year).First(itm => itm.Code == cod))
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! It's very very few code! It' a little bit hard to uderstand it for me (with LINQ I'm not already so 'advanced'). And then it's quite hard for me to convert it in VB. Could you, please, help me a little more, and give me the query in VB?

Comment: Did my best. Sorry for the errors. I don't have VB.NET installed to check. Dim distinctCodes = (From item in items _
 Select item.Code).Distinct


Dim filteredItems = distinctCodes _
        .Select(Function(cod) items.OrderBy(Function(itm) itm.Year).First(Function(itm) itm.Code == cod)) _
        .ToList()

Comment: Thank you very very much!!! I have a little error, that I should resolve tomorrow ("no 'select' accessible, impossible to infer the type, etc.") But expecially I have to study a bit to learn this kind of queries!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can google for "Concordance source code" in your preferred implementation language.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but the proposed solution absolutely doesn't fullfill Pileggi's initial requirements.
"The less common value as possible" has become "the min value".
Both match in this precise case, which gives the illusion that Alex Aza's answer is right but it is just a coincidence.